# General information about backups made in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an automatic backup function in Laravel, which is processed once a day. In discord via webhook I receive information that backups have started, here is my `AutomaticBackupCommand` process function:

```
protected $backupStatusCollection = [];

    public function handle()
    {
        $excludedNodes = json_decode($this->settingsRepository->get('backup::auto::excluded', '{}'), true);

        $webhookUrl = 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/...';
        // Message title
        $title = ' Automatic Backups';

        // Content
        $content = '[ ⌛️ ] - Automatic Servers Backups started';

        $embed = [
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $content,
            'color' => hexdec('00ff00'), 
        ];

        $response = Http::post($webhookUrl, [
            'embeds' => [$embed],
        ]);

        $this->backupStatusCollection = [];

        foreach (Server::query()->whereNull('status')->whereNotIn('node_id', $excludedNodes)->get() as $server) {
            // Create backup every day
            $server->backup_limit += 1;
            $server->automatic_backup = true;
            $backupName = str_replace('[DATE]', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'), $this->settingsRepository->get('backup::auto::name', 'Automatic Backup [DATE]'));

            try {
                $this->initiateBackupService->handle($server, $backupName);
            } catch (TooManyBackupsException|\Throwable $e) {
                $this->line(sprintf('Failed to start the backup creation for %s', $server->uuidShort));
            }

            // Delete old automatic backups
            $daysToStore = $this->settingsRepository->get('backup::auto::days', 0);
            $weeksToStore = $this->settingsRepository->get('backup::auto::weeks', 0);
            $monthsToStore = $this->settingsRepository->get('backup::auto::months', 0);
            $backups = $server->backups()->where('is_automatic', '=', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

            foreach ($backups as $key => $backup) {
                $daysInDiff = Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($backup->created_at)))->diffInDays(Carbon::now());

                // Check every day store
                if ($daysInDiff < $daysToStore) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Check week store
                if ($daysInDiff < $daysToStore + ($weeksToStore * 7)) {
                    if (self::hasEarlierBackupForWeek($backups, $key)) {
                        $this->deleteBackup($backup);
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                // Check month store
                if ($daysInDiff < Carbon::now()->subDays($daysToStore + ($weeksToStore * 7))->subMonths($monthsToStore)->diffInDays(Carbon::now())) {
                    if (self::hasEarlierBackupForMonth($backups, $key)) {
                        $this->deleteBackup($backup);
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                // Delete in every other case
                $this->deleteBackup($backup);
            }
        }
    }
```

And there is a `BackupStatusController` controller, which processes the status of all backups, and then sends information to discord that all backups are completed, the name of the server, successful backups: this much, unsuccessful backups: this much. This is my code:

```
    public function __construct(private BackupManager $backupManager)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Handles updating the state of a backup.
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function index(ReportBackupCompleteRequest $request, string $backup): JsonResponse
    {
        $model = Backup::query()->where('uuid', $backup)->firstOrFail();

        if ($model->is_successful) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('Cannot update the status of a backup that is already marked as completed.');
        }

        $action = $request->boolean('successful') ? 'server:backup.complete' : 'server:backup.fail';
        $log = Activity::event($action)->subject($model, $model->server)->property('name', $model->name);

        $log->transaction(function () use ($model, $request) {
            $successful = $request->boolean('successful');

            $model->fill([
                'is_successful' => $successful,
                'is_locked' => $successful ? $model->is_locked : false,
                'checksum' => $successful ? ($request->input('checksum_type') . ':' . $request->input('checksum')) : null,
                'bytes' => $successful ? $request->input('size') : 0,
                'completed_at' => CarbonImmutable::now(),
            ])->save();

            $adapter = $this->backupManager->adapter();
            if ($adapter instanceof S3Filesystem) {
                $this->completeMultipartUpload($model, $adapter, $successful, $request->input('parts'));
            }
        });

        $backupInfo = [
            'backup_uuid' => $backup,
            'is_successful' => $model->is_successful,
            'server_uuid' => $model->server->uuidShort,
            'node_name' => $model->server->node->name,
        ];

        $this->backupStatusCollection[] = $backupInfo;

        if ($this->areAllBackupsCompleted()) {
            $this->handleBackupsCompleted();
        }

        return new JsonResponse([], JsonResponse::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }

    protected function areAllBackupsCompleted(): bool
    {
        foreach ($this->backupStatusCollection as $backupInfo) {
            if (!$backupInfo['is_successful']) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected function handleBackupsCompleted()
    {
        $failureCount = 0;
        $successBackupsInfo = '';
        $problemNodes = [];
        $problemServers = [];

        foreach ($this->backupStatusCollection as $backupInfo) {
            if (!$backupInfo['is_successful']) {
                $failureCount++;
                $problemNodes[] = $backupInfo['node_name'];
                $problemServers[] = $backupInfo['server_uuid'];
            } else {
                $successBackupsInfo .= "Server UUID: {$backupInfo['server_uuid']}, Node: {$backupInfo['node_name']}\n";
            }
        }

        $webhookUrl = 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/...';
        $title = ' Automatic Backups Completed';
        $content = "[ ✅ ] - Automatic Servers Backups completed\n";

        if ($failureCount > 0) {
            $problemNodesString = implode(', ', array_unique($problemNodes));
            $problemServersString = implode(', ', array_unique($problemServers));
            $content .= "@everyone\n";
            $content .= "\n❌ There were {$failureCount} failed backups in: {$problemNodesString} node(s). Problem server(s): " . implode(', ', $problemServersString) . ".";
        }

        $successCount = count($this->backupStatusCollection) - $failureCount;
        $content .= "Successful Backups: {$successCount}\n{$successBackupsInfo}";
        $content .= "Failed Backups: {$failureCount}\n";


        $embed = [
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $content,
            'color' => hexdec('00ff00'),
        ];

        Http::post($webhookUrl, ['embeds' => [$embed]]);
        $this->backupStatusCollection = [];
    }
```

Here I display all the information about the backup; if there is a problem with the backup, I use the @everyone mention to react.
Now 2 backups are being made, the problem is that I receive 2 messages on discord, like this:

```
 Automatic Backups Completed
[✅] - Automatic Servers Backups completed
Successful Backups: 1
Server UUID: 5c8f2e1c, Node: hel1.fin
Failed Backups: 0

 Automatic Backups Completed
[✅] - Automatic Servers Backups completed
Successful Backups: 1
Server UUID: 243c4344, Node: hel1.fin
Failed Backups: 0
```

But I need only 1 message to arrive, which will contain the total number of successful and total number of unsuccessful backups, like this:

```
 Automatic Backups Completed
[✅] - Automatic Servers Backups completed
Node: hel1.fin
Successful Backups: 2
Failed Backups: 0
```

What could be the problem, how can I change this and send messages normally and receive only 1 message with total stats?

How i understand, information is sent immediately as soon as 1 backup is completed and then information about the second backup is sent when it has also been completed. As I understand it, I don’t need to send this information, but simply store it, and after all the backups are completed, process the received information and display statistics on the backups.